# GAE sub-domain within app.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is it possible to configure app.yaml to use two distinct PHP scripts, with one handling the naked domain and another handling all other sub-domains?

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: naked.php
- url: /.*.mydomain.com
  script: sub-domains.php
```

I am reading up on modules right now - is this what will solve my problem?

EDIT | This link leads me to believe I can achieve what I am after by using services and a custom dispatch configuration?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dispatchref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using the `app.yaml` pattern routing since the patterns are applied only on the file path portion of the requested URL (without the domain name).

Yes, modules can be mapped to different domains, with routing based on the `dispatch.yaml` file, which would look somehow along these lines:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "mydomain.com/*"
    module: naked_domain_module

  - url: "*mydomain.com/*"
    module: subdomain_module
```

Notes:

- the order of rules in the `dispatch.yaml` matters - first match wins
- requests with no matches are sent to the default module (you may need to shuffle the rule order/content, depending if you want to make one of the modules the default one)
- you can't test this routing on the devserver (which doesn't support hostname routing) unless you also have a more specific pattern in the request path - maybe for local testing only? - for which you can add a dispatch rule,

like this:

```
- url: "*/naked/*"
  module: naked_domain_module
```

But in this case you need to account for that added path pattern in the `naked_domain_module`'s `app.yaml` routing as well and revert it when deploying in production. If you keep this path pattern in production then you don't need all this module story as you can latch on it in the `app.yaml` directly.

Clarification: just the automatic routing using the dispatch file doesn't work with the local devserver, the modules work fine except you need to make the requests to the respective module "domains" (actually different listenting ports) yourself. This is a sample of how the devserver behaves in such case, showing the base URL for each module:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host 0.0.0.0 --log_level=debug dispatch.yaml main/main.yaml buildin/buildin.yaml
WARNING  2016-08-16 16:11:18,474 application_configuration.py:786] Hostname routing is not supported by the development server. The following dispatch entries will not match any requests:
<DispatchEntry 
    url=buildin-dot-myapp.appspot.com/* 
    service=None 
    module=buildin
    >
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,506 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,716 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,884 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:36398
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,885 dispatcher.py:185] Starting dispatcher running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,890 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8081
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,893 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "buildin" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8082
INFO     2016-08-16 16:11:18,897 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for App Engine dispatching:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/how-requests-are-routed

Details on the dispatch.yaml are here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/dispatchref

Hope this helps!